# Add new column and aggregate data

Tags: r

I am a novice at R programming and stuck with a problem.

Here's a sample dataset:

```
 df <- data.frame(
      area_id = c(31,34,36,33,28,35, 31,34,36,33,28,35),
      description = c('paramount','sony','star','miramax','pixar','zee', 'paramount','sony','star','miramax','pixar','zee'),
      footfall = c(200, 354, 543, 123, 456, 634, 356, 765, 345, 235, 657, 524),
      income = c(21000, 19000, 35000, 18000, 12000, 190000, 21000, 19000, 35000, 18000, 12000, 190000),
      year = c(2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020));
```

Now, I have two requirements:

1. Adding a column named "region" with values based on "area_id";
   So, areas with "area_id" = 28, 34, 36 should  have value as "West" in "region" column.
   Similarly, areas with "area_id" = 31, 33, 35 should  have value as "East" in "region" column.
2. Finally, I want a summary table stratified by year and aggregated region-wise. The final table should look like below:

[image]

Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this

```
library(tidyverse)

west <- c(28, 34, 36)

df %>% mutate(region = case_when(area_id %in% west ~ "West",
                                 TRUE ~ "East")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(footfall, income), names_to = "Header", values_to = "val") %>%
  group_by(region, Header, year) %>% summarise(val = sum(val)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(region, Header), names_from = year, values_from = val) %>%
  mutate(Total = `2019` + `2020`) -> df2

# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   region, Header [4]
  region Header   `2019` `2020`  Total
  <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 East   footfall    957   1115   2072
2 East   income   229000 229000 458000
3 West   footfall   1353   1767   3120
4 West   income    66000  66000 132000
```

If you assign the above result to say `df2` and check its `class`

```
class(df2)

[1]   "tbl_df"   "tbl"     "data.frame"
```

which will be same as that of `class(df)`

Comment: is there a way where I can get a dataframe instead of tibble?

Comment: data.frame and tibble aren't different except in their printing method.

Comment: Check my edited answer.  Still you are free to use `data.frame(df2)` to have it behave like dataframe